# how to access added elements by php from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a small project and it is my first so, I have some difficulties to get over.
I am creating a dynamic list for a filtered search and the problem is that I try to add elements with php and I want them to change visibility onclick and for that I use a css code which is fully functional but the problem is with the javascript which tells me:

> script.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of
>   null
>       at visibilityToggle (script.js:4)
>       at HTMLDivElement.onclick (afficherDept.php:4)

js_Code:

```
function visibilityToggle(id) {
    var section = document.getElementById(id);
    section.classList().toggle("showen");
}
```

and this is the php code for adding elements:
---$sectionID is controlled by a loop

```
echo '<div onclick="visibilityToggle('.$sectionID.');"id='.$id.'>'.'ID 
     '.$dept["id"].'. NOM:'. $dept["nom"].'.CHEF:'.$dept["chef"].'</div>';

echo '<section class="hidden" id=' . $sectionID . '>';
```

[result in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw2zI.png)

Comment: well, `visibilityToggle('.$sectionID.');` needs to be `visibilityToggle(\''.$sectionID.'\');`

Comment: Also, be aware that JavaScript and PHP have no relation to one another whatsoever. All the JavaScript sees is the resultant HTML; by the time JS is in play, PHP has long gone. The JS doesn't know (or care) whether the HTML was generated statically, by PHP, or some other means.

Comment: also, `classList` is a read-only property, not a function. Thus, you shouldn't use `()`after the identifier

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to call a function with `onclick` from an element, and then use `document.getElementById` to search for the same element again...

Instead I would add a class to your divs in PHP, and use javascript to add a click handler. This way you know who called the handler and you can toggle the CSS class directly. (note: haven't tested this but I hope the idea is clear)

PHP

```
echo '<div class="clickablediv">simple example</div>';
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let clickableDivs = document.getElementsByClassname("clickablediv")
for(let d of clickableDivs){
    d.addEventListener("click", visibilityToggle)
}
function visibilityToggle(e) {
    e.target.classList().toggle("showen");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the denoted error is the wrongful rendering of the html markup from your php code.

You need to put quotes around the argument passed to the `visibilityToggle` function.

```
'<div onclick="visibilityToggle(\''. $sectionID. '\')"'
```

Next, the classList is a `DOMTokenList` object - not a function.

So, you should access the `toggle` property like this:

```
section.classList.toggle("showen");
```

Answer (score 0):

`thanks for all your answers.` I fixed the problem. In my js function visibilityToggle, the argument id was a html element not a string. i don't know why but it worke